# How to retrieve username and password in another class?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

The following LOGINFORM class stores the correct username and password which were used to login to a GUI.

LOGIN CLASS....

```
public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

String username;
String password;

//rest of code here
```

how do i retrieve the Loginform username and password to be used in the prepared statement in another class in the line 
("SELECT * FROM AcademicInfo where Email=? and Password=?"); replacing the ? , which would enable me to obtain a specific field in from sql database?

RETRIEVE CLASS....

```
public void retrieveAcademic() {

try {
pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AcademicInfo where Username=? and Password=?");
rs = pst.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
          title = (rs.getString(2));
          forename = (rs.getString(3));
          surname = (rs.getString(4));
          role = (rs.getString(5));
          room = (rs.getString(6));
          page = (rs.getString(7));
          hours = (rs.getString(8));
          phone = (rs.getString(9));
          mobile = (rs.getString(10));
          email = (rs.getString(11));


         } //end while
  }
```

Comment: Wow, that is really basic. I suggest you read a book about Java first.

Comment: You told us nothing at all. Where is `retrieveAcademic()` written (which class)?

Comment: a serperate class which instantiates LoginForm object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Loginform` needs a *reference* to an instance of the class containing the `retrieveAcademic()` method. How you create/pass that reference depends enormously on the structure of your application (e.g. via dependency injection, a simple construction etc.).

Note that an alternative is for your db-related class to have a reference to `LoginForm` and call appropriate getters e.g. `getPassword()` and `getUsername()`

I suspect however that you want some sort of *model* object containing these credentials such that other components can access them as/when required. Your login form is transitory and you may have other means of logging in in the future(e.g. you may have a web service or similar). I realise this is perhaps thinking far ahead, but you get the idea.

The simplest way to then pass the username/password is to pass them as 2 arguments e.g.

```
db.retrieveAcademic(username, password);
```

and in the method call [PreparedStatement.setString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) for the appropriate fields.

(you may want to wrap the `username` and `password` fields into a separate object `Credentials` or similar, but that's for later)

Comment: i am not passing username and password from retrieve academic, rather want to obtain the stored username and password variable from loginform into retrieveAcademic() to excute the statement. atm null is given so not able to access the variable.

Comment: @MuminAli. You shouldn't do it like you're doing it. The Login Frame should exist only during the login. After that, it should start the GUI and pass the credentials to the started GUI.

Comment: so if i create a bean for username and password and use the getUsername in the preapreStatement line would that be a good way to do it?